# WPF DataGrid not appear in Toolbox?

Tags: datagrid, wpftoolkit, toolbox, .net-4.0, wpf-4.0

I am working with Visual studio 2008. I want to work on WPF DataGrid control.

I downloaded [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) and install it, and then added toolkit reference in my project, but it does not recognize Datagrid control, and does not show it in Toolbox, I even try to add it in toolbox through **choose Item..**  but when I click WPFToolkit.dll, it gives the error. And even if I write code in XAML it does not recognize dataGrid.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have selected the WPF Components tab before pressing browse. You are telling it to look for WinForms controls in your screenshot.